# show and hide warnings in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to angularjs, I want to show and hide a message with data-ng-show (it is a warning message) based on a condition in my javascript is there anyway to handle it like validations set some functions like ngModel.$setValidity('range', true)- I dont want it to act like validation and prevent submitting.

this is my code:

```
            var showMessage = (value) => {

            legalDate = new Date();
            legalDate.setFullYear(legalDate.getFullYear() - 21);

            var dateValue = new Date(year, month, day);


            if (value != null && value !== "" && dateValue.getTime() > legalDate.getTime()) { //DOB indicates >12 and <21
               // $('.under21').show(); ==> something like this: ngModel.$setValidity('range', true);
            }
            else {
               // $('.under21').hide();
            }

            return value;

        }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a scope variable in the condition and then use that in the html markup. Something like this:

```
//Set the scope variable;
$scope.showElement = false;
var showMessage = (value) => {

        legalDate = new Date();
        legalDate.setFullYear(legalDate.getFullYear() - 21);

        var dateValue = new Date(year, month, day);


        if (value != null && value !== "" && dateValue.getTime() > legalDate.getTime()) { //DOB indicates >12 and <21
           $scope.showElement = true;
        }
        else {
          $scope.showElement = false;
        }

        return value;

    }
```

And in the html markup say you have a span on which you need to show/hide:

```
<span class="under21" ng-show="showElement"></span>
```